# Is it necessary to maintain high and low variables in binary search?

Tags: java, data-structures

I implemented it using just n, as the low will be 0 anyways, but talking about the 'right algorithmic way' is it necessary for high and low vars to be present? My Implementation:

```
public class ArrayBinarySearch {


    static int binarySearch(int[] a, int n, int key) {
        int mid = n / 2;

        if (key >= a[mid]) {
            for (int i = mid; i < n; i++) {
                if (a[i] == key)
                    return i;
            }
        }

        if (key < a[mid]) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
                if (a[i] == key)
                    return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {
            1,
            2,
            3,
            6,
            8,
            10,
            29
        };
        int find = 29;

        int posn = binarySearch(a, a.length, find);

        if (posn == -1) {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found at " + (posn + 1));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a binary search. It is essentially a linear search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've not implemented a proper binary search.

Or put differently: a "real" binary search would recursively half the search-space multiple times until it finds the value (or decides it can't be found).

Your code only halves the search space **once**: you decide which half of the array potentially contains the relevant data and then do a linear search of that half.

For small-ish arrays the code you implemented will be very close to the same performance (and might even be a tad faster in some extreme cases), but for large arrays, you'll have a lot more accesses than are really necessary.

For example if you have an array with 4000 elements, then a proper binary search would need at most 12 comparisons to find the element (since each comparison halves the amount of possible places).

Your implementation will require at most 2001 comparisons to find the element.

And to answer your specific question: yes, a proper binary search needs both ends, because otherwise you can't distinguish which part of the array to search. It could be the first half, the second quarter, the third 1/8th of the array, ...

Only a very small number of all possible subsets to search for starts at the beginning (or the exact middle) of the array.

Comment: oh my god, i understand now!! thanks so much

Comment: really well explained thankyou!